# How to enable or disable a mobilesubstrate via a preference bundle

Tags: iphone, ios, cydia, tweak, logos

I would like to know that suppose I have a tweak how would i enable people to enable or disable it via a switch? I need help for a current tweak im working on. This is a mobile substrate  tweak made by logos in Theos

Comment: Here's [some information on using Preference Bundles](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/PreferenceBundles)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Preferences plist as exemplified in *a lot* of opensource MobileSubstrate-based projects and as documented [here](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/PreferenceLoader).

Then, decently check if your tweak is enabled in your hooks where you find this to be most necessary, and that's it.

Note that when checking for Preferences, do it right. [This function](https://github.com/DHowett/cydelete/blob/master/Hook.xm#L51) is a great example of doing this.